# Any way of streaming over Icecast with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, icecast

I'm looking for a way of streaming audio data in the form of float values over an icecast stream using nodejs or another similar framework. I've had a look at certain frameworks, but they all seem to only either read data from or inject metadata to an existing stream.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "over an Icecast stream"?  You want to send data to an Icecast server with your Node.js app being the source stream?  You want to relay a stream from an Icecast server?  You want to stream audio over HTTP to clients?

Comment: I want to stream audio over HTTP to clients. I plan on generating this audio in Node as well, which I hope won't be so slow as to cause buffer underrun errors.

Comment: I'm doing this now in a couple of my projects with good success.  It works quite well.  There really isn't much off-the-shelf code for this sort of thing, but you don't really need it.  Node.js has a built-in HTTP server that works well.

Comment: Do you have a github where I could see the source of one of your projects?

Comment: Sorry, the code is proprietary.  All you have to do is send your data in response to an HTTP request using the built-in HTTP server.  The example on Node.js' home page is a good place to start.